# JS load image on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I need to load an image, js need to get link url and print this image on screen.
But it is not working.

What is wrong with my script? what can I do to make it work and improve it?

html

```
<div id=img></div>

<div id=loading></div>


<a href=http://png-5.findicons.com/files/icons/1580/devine_icons_part_2/128/my_computer.png class=postmini>Open image 1</a>
<br>
<a href=http://www.iconshock.com/img_jpg/BETA/communications/jpg/256/smile_icon.jpg class=postmini>Open image 2</a>
```

js

```
$(function() {
$(".postmini").click(function(){

var element = $(this);
var I = element.attr("href");

$("#loading").html('<img src="loader.gif" align="absmiddle">&nbsp;loading...');

$("#loading").ajaxComplete(function(){}).slideUp();
$("#img").append(I);

 });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/u6j2udzb/

and this loading div, what I need to do to make it work properly?

Comment: Where is your ajax code? Please read on ajax first http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ .

Comment: sorry, in fact it is a jquery

Comment: everything is wrong about that :) first you should add quotes around href links in html, second you are using ajax complete global event i.e calls on ajax success completion and you never made ajax call btw.

Comment: Why don't you just change the "src" attribute of the image... oO

Comment: quotes are not necessary since html 2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a lot and have a lot you don't need. I have commented out where you don't need items. In particular you don't need a loading because the image will be there before they see that. However, if you do want it still, you should be loading it underneath the image you are loading. So it gets covered by the image. I can update it with that if you'd like.

What you are missing is actual code to turn the href into an image source and you are not removing the default action of the anchor tag so it doesn't try loading a new page when clicked.

```
$(".postmini").click(function(event){
event.preventDefault();
var element = $(this);
var I = element.attr("href");

//$("#loading").html('loading...');

//$("#loading").ajaxComplete(function(){}).slideUp();
// remove old image if it is already there.
$("#img").empty();
// create variable holding the image src from the href link
var img = $("<img/>").attr("src", I)

$("#img").append(img);

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3g8ujLvd/

Answer (score 1):

You just have to insert an img tag into your "display div" on click on the link... to load the image... (btw your syntax errors are terrible... you have to use quotes for attributes^^)

like this for example :

```
$('.postmini').on('click',function(){
    //do something
});
```

Check this : https://jsfiddle.net/u6j2udzb/8/
(done quickly for example)

Hope it helps

Comment: Much more elegant than my answer. Only suggestion would be to add the loading to the #img container and use CSS to display it underneath the image so that it gets covered up on load.

Comment: @V_RocKs just did it quickly without thinking about the "loading" thing... this was just to show the idea so that he could go further on his own. But you're right. There are several ways to improve my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You are not running an ajax script. ajaxComplete is only fired after an ajax [script completed](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxcomplete/).

> Whenever an Ajax request completes, jQuery triggers the ajaxComplete
>   event. Any and all handlers that have been registered with the
>   .ajaxComplete() method are executed at this time.

You should ad an [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) script and than ajaxComplete will run if you registered the ajaxComplete method.

Comment: but i dont need to call php to print this image. what I need is just get url and print it on the div img.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment you're just placing the text from the "href" attribute on the link into the div. You need to either create an image or use the link provided as a background.

The quickest way to see this is to change make this change:

```
var element = $(this);
var I = element.attr("href");

$("#loading").html('<img src="loader.gif" align="absmiddle">&nbsp;loading...');

$("#loading").ajaxComplete(function(){}).slideUp();
// $("#img").append(I);
$("#img").html("<img src='"+I+"' />");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.postmini').on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#loading').html('<img src="'+this.href+'">').children('img').one('load',function(){$(this).parent().slideUp('slow');});
});
```

Noticed I used `on` instead of `click` this allows you to use `this.href` rather than a more lengthy `$(this).attr('href')`. I also used `.one` on a child image element to find out if the image has loaded.

But I've just realised that this is useless because you want to have a loader. Ma bad.

```
$('.postmini').on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    //best have the loader.gif showing on default before the load is complete.
    var img=$('<img class="loadedImage">');
    img.src=this.href;
    //img.css({display:none;});//remove this if you've enter CSS .loadedImage{display:none;}
    $('#loading').append(img).slideDown('slow',function(){$(this).children('.loadedImage').one('load',function(){$(this).fadeIn('slow');$(this).siblings('img[src="loader.gif"]').hide();});});
});
```

This method is what you're looking for. Basically you want to click the link, stop the default action of going to the link, make a new image element and set the src, make sure it's hidden before load, add the new image element to loading, slide up parent loading, check for load and fade in :)

Comment: oh, I will check it now and come to tell if it works!

Comment: Oh and another tip. when using attributes. Please use string quotes like `class="postmini"` and `href="http://www.whatever.com"`

Answer (score 0):

Try and run this simple snippet

```js
$('#myButton').click(()=>{

  let imgUrl = $('#imgUrl').val();
  
  $.get(imgUrl)
  .done(() => {
    $('img').attr('src', imgUrl);
    $('#imgText').text('');
  })
  .fail(() => {
    $('#imgText').text('Image does not exist');
    $('img').attr('src', '');
  })

})
```

```css
img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Image url: <input type="text" id="imgUrl" value="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/75/Woman_mechanic_working_on_engine_%28cropped%29.jpeg"><br>
<button id="myButton" type="button">click here to load image</button>

<div id="imgText"></div>
<img>
```